# Image numbering depending on the partition number in which the image is displayed

Tags: image, label, latex, figure, caption

How can I make captions under images in Fig. 1.1:, Fig. 1.2:, Fig. 2.1:, Fig. 2.2: depending on the section number and not just sequentially from 1 for all images in the article

For example code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}   
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/1.png}
    \caption{caption 1}\label{Fig_1}

    \endminipage\hfill

    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/2.png}
    \caption{caption 2}\label{Fig_2}

    \endminipage\hfill

    \minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/3.png}
    \caption{caption 3}\label{Fig_3}
    \endminipage
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any additional packages, latex itself provides the macro `\counterwithin`  which allows to number the figures on a per section basis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}   
%       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{caption 1}
        \label{Fig_1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}%
%       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{caption 2}
        \label{Fig_2}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}%
%       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{caption 3}
        \label{Fig_3}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(`\centering` is not necessary if the images already have the same width as the `minipage`)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to this question in tex.stackechange https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume
It redefines counters with the `chngcntr` package.

But in my opinion, the simpler is to use the `float`package. It allows to redefine floating environments, with  a specific graphic appearance, position, etc, and numbering scheme.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

% We define a new float environment called image.
% htbp means 'images' will be positioned preferably here, then at top, bottom or   
% on a new page
% info on labels will go to file xx.lim (list of images)
% and it will numbered within sections
\newfloat{image}{htbp}{lim}[section]
% and we want 'Fig.' to appear on the caption
\floatname{image}{Fig.}
\begin{document}

\section{A first section}
blah blah. Look at image \ref{im1}. blah blah
\begin{image}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
  \caption{An image}\label{im1}
\end{image}

\section{A second section}
blah blah. And now consider images \ref{im2} and \ref{im3}. blah blah
\begin{image}
  \centering
\hfill\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\hfill
  \caption{Now a bunch with several images}\label{im2}
\end{image}

blah blah
\begin{image}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}    &\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\\
    Image A&Image B
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{And two last images}\label{im3}
\end{image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have several images in a fig, just place them as any text. In TeX, images are considered as (large) characters and the standard positioning methods apply. In the first example, I used `\hfill` to spread them evenly on a line, and in the second a tabular to include small comments on the images. But many other methods, like minipages, can be used. But if your image set is too long to fit on a line, unwanted line breaks may appear.

Unrelated, but any people use the `float` package because it also defines a new placement directive 'H' that means more or less 'place the float Here and nowhere else'. And modifying the graphics appearance of floats is also very useful.

Here is another solution without the float package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

% change counter numbering
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}
blah blah. Look at images \ref{im1}, \ref{im2} and \ref{im3}. blah blah
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{image 1}\label{im1}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{image 2}\label{im2}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{image 3}\label{im3}
  \end{minipage}
  \centering
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Merigon, Thank you instead of telling me how to handle multiple images in one container {figure} (added example to the question description)? Because when I used the method you suggested for this type of image, the signature was displayed on the left (under the first image), but for the right (third) image

Comment: I do not understand your problem. In my example, captions are correctly displayed at the center of the "figure". If you want a figure with several images,  you must first positions them with any method and include them in the float. I updated the answer with two ways to include several images in a figure, but many methods exist. But the caption is always centered.

Comment: I meant (as in the question in the example) - 1 block {figure}, which contains 3 images and 3 captions under images - Fig. 1.1, Fig. 1.2, Fig. 1.3, and you have 1 block {image}, which contains 3 images, but only 1 numbering Fig. 1.1

Comment: This is a completely different problem. Figures and derived floats are "floating" environments. As such, you cannot finely control their position by putting them side by side in a non floating environment. There is the  "subfigure" package that allows to put two or more images in a figure. But it does not work with the 'float' package. Also, you can use the 'capt-of' package to generate a caption out of a figure and hand typeset your images and captions. But it also does not work with custom floating environment.

Comment: The best solution would be to adapt the solution in the tex.SE answer that I mentioned to figures for the per section numbering. And either to use subfigures or put several images with their captions in minipages and put them all in a unique figure environment.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the original figure environment and showned in an example how to put several images side by side.

Comment: The `\usepackage{chngcntr}` in the last code block is unnecessary